# Latex multiple picture inside a single one figure

Tags: graphics, floats

There is a few paragraph of dummy text. After that I want the figure to be forced below the text. The figure contains multiple `includegraphics` pictures, and it does not fit into one page, thus the figure should cut in half at a certain point (latex should decide where, when the page is full).

Currently what I have:

**Page-1**

[image]

**Page-2**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\selectlanguage{magyar}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}  


\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\marginsize{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{1.0cm}{1.0cm}

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,        
    unicode=false,           
    pdftitle={...},       
    pdfauthor={...},   
    pdfsubject={...}, 
    pdfcreator={...},   
    pdfproducer={Producer},   
    pdfkeywords={keywords},  
    pdfnewwindow=true,     
    colorlinks=true,          
    linkcolor=black,          
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}


  \caption{\normalfont {figure}}
  \label{fig:large-fig}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

What I want:

**Page-1**

[image]

**Page-2**

[image]

Comment: the answer is a fusion of this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668932/how-can-i-use-a-for-loop-to-display-50-pictures-on-a-page and this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669130/spanning-figures-over-multiple-pages

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` in current latex or  `\usepackage{epsfig}` in any document written after 1994

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want a float, so simply remove the `figure`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

%%no \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% no!! \usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\selectlanguage{magyar}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}  


\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\marginsize{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{1.0cm}{1.0cm}

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,        
    unicode=false,           
    pdftitle={...},       
    pdfauthor={...},   
    pdfsubject={...}, 
    pdfcreator={...},   
    pdfproducer={Producer},   
    pdfkeywords={keywords},  
    pdfnewwindow=true,     
    colorlinks=true,          
    linkcolor=black,          
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}


  \captionof{figure}{\normalfont {figure}}
  \label{fig:large-fig}
\end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This puts each row into a separate figure.  The first uses [b] and the rest [bt!] to bypass the `\@botnum` and `\@topnum` limits.  This forces the floats to either be at the top or bottom of a page, making them contiguous.

I commented out all the irrelevant or unused packages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{listingsutf8}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{anysize}
%\usepackage[magyar]{babel}% you want me to load ANOTHER language
%\selectlanguage{magyar}
%\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}  


\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
%\marginsize{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{1.0cm}{1.0cm}% I don't know what package this is from
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,        
    unicode=false,           
    pdftitle={...},       
    pdfauthor={...},   
    pdfsubject={...}, 
    pdfcreator={...},   
    pdfproducer={Producer},   
    pdfkeywords={keywords},  
    pdfnewwindow=true,     
    colorlinks=true,          
    linkcolor=black,          
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[bt!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[bt!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[bt!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[bt!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[bt!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[bt!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[bt!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[bt!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
  \caption{\normalfont {figure}}
  \label{fig:large-fig}
\end{figure}

\newpage% prevent following text from printing on first page
\lipsum[4-5]
    
\end{document}
```

The first four floats are placed in `\@botlist` immediately and `\pagegoal` is reduced accordingly.  The remainder are placed in `\@deferlist` until shipout (`\newpage`) when they are moved to `\@toplist` on the new page.